# How to Find the probability for a normal distribution

Tags: probability, random-variables, normal-distribution, means, standard-deviation

It is known that the income of guests at an all-inclusive resort on the north coast is normally distributed with a standard deviation of $\$8000$.

---

Suppose a random sample of $50$ guests is taken:

a) What is the probability that the sample standard deviation of incomes is at least $\$5000\ ?$.

b) What is the probability that the standard deviation of the incomes for this sample is no more than $\$1000\ ?$.

With the questions above, I have tried to find the probability but I’ve never solved one of this without being provided with the mean, this is what I’m used to:

- First finding the z-score, $\left(5000 - \mbox{mean}\right)/\mbox{standard deviation}$.
- Then look for the value in the normal distribution table.

Comment: Note:  the formatting system attaches special meaning to dollar signs so you can't use them casually; that's why your post was so garbled.  If you click on Edit you can see the syntax I used to include the symbols you wanted.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: Your approach seems not wrong. What are your figures?

Comment: Okay. This is what I know:  SD: 8000.    N: 50 Df: n-1. How should I proceed then. Is it then to find the variance then plug it in to P(n-1) SD / S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $\ V\ $ is the sample *variance*
$$
V=\frac{1}{49}\sum_{i=1}^{50}\left(X_i-\frac{1}{50}\sum_{j=1}^{50}X_j\right)^2
$$
—that is the *square* of the sample standard deviation $\ S\ $—then the random variable
$$
\frac{49V}{8000^2}=\frac{49S^2}{8000^2}
$$
follows a chi-squared distribution with $49$ degrees of freedom, *regardless of the mean income*.  Now
$$
S\ge5000\Leftrightarrow \frac{49S^2}{8000^2}\ge49\left(\frac{5}{8}\right)^2\ .
$$
Therefore, the probability that the sample standard deviation is at least $\$5000$ is $\ 1-\chi^2_{49}\left(\frac{1225}{64}\right)\ $.  Likewise, the probability that the sample standard deviation is no more than $\$1000$ is $\ \chi^2_{49}\left(\frac{49}{64}\right)\ $.